# How can I prefer WLAN over Ethernet when it is available in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet

**The Problem:**

I have a Windows 10 Machine with a built in Network Card. I also have a external wireless Dongle. 
That is because I have 2 different internet Connections.

- The LAN is Connected to my "Wired" ISP for gaming ==> Because I only got 5 Mbit/s for this Connection but a good ping.
- The WLAN is connected to the LTE Router from another ISP because I got high Speed with it but bad Ping. I only enable this when I'm about to Download something

Now I want to have this setting:

If I'm about to put in the wifi dongle - it should automatically connect with wireless and prefer it over the ethernet connection. But it doesn't

**What I have tried so far:**

- I changed the Ethernet Metric to 20
- Changed the WLAN Metric to 10 and restarted the computer afterwards
- I tried to change the priority like I did in Windows 7 but I no more have this option under Windows 10 (Advanced - Advanced Settings). But when I do this I just have this window:

[image: settings screenshot]

So right now I don't know what else I could try. 
It always prefers the Ethernet and I have to manually navigate into the settings and disable the whole connection and repeat it after download has finished. 
I know it's not too annoying but why not solve it to work a little bit more "comfortable".

Any tips appreciated. If you need more informations or I forgot something let me know.